# Application can not be started

Tags: c#, wpf, process, launch

I was trying to start a `WPF application` for UI test in 2 different way, but failed in both way.

`Application application = Application.Launch(@"D:\pathOfTheEXE");`

and

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\pathOfTheEXE");
Process process = null;
Retry.For(() => {
   process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
   process.WaitForInputIdle(10000);
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `WaitForExit` instead of `WaitForIdleInput`, you're not providing it with an input stream so the process is probably terminating before it has a chance to do anything.

Comment: change  `Process process = null;` to `Process process =new Process ();` and `process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);` to `process.Start(processStartInfo);`